# Try to get facebook profile on click - react native

Tags: facebook, sdk, react-native

Hello i tried to get the facebook profile info of user when he press button:
like this:

```
const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
    LoginManager
} = FBSDK;

regFacebook() {
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile']).then(
        function(result) {
            if (result.isCancelled) {
                Alert.alert(
                    "cancel",
                    "cancel"
                );
            } else {
                Alert.alert(
                    "success",
                    "success"
                );
            }
        },
        function(error) {
            Alert.alert(
                "error",
                "error"
            );
        }
    );
}
```

but when i press its not doing any alert...
its open the facebook premission i give the premission and not get any alert back...

and in another click (when there is a premission) its show loading and not alert nothing too...

actually i doing it with LoginManager and not loginButton because i want my own button styles and text...

working with react native 0.36.1
and android

tnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

hi friends you replace this code for

```
LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile'])
        .then(function(result) {
              if (result.isCancelled) {
                 alert('Login cancelled');
              } else {
                 return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(); //this return public profile
              }
           },
           function(error) {
              alert('Login fail with error: ' + error);
           }
        );
```